# How Do I Query Azure Active Directory For An Application Client Secret?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to link my API Management with an Azure Active Directory Identity Provider.

In order to do that I have to use the REST API which requires the client secret as a part of the body:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/identityprovider/createorupdate

I don't want to check in the client secret to source control so I thought I would retrieve the client secret from Active Directory on the fly:

When I try to [list the app credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-credential-list) with `az ad app credential list --id xxxx-my-long-id-xxx` it doesn't return the secret:

```
[
  {
    "additionalProperties": null,
    "customKeyIdentifier": null,
    "endDate": "2020-08-16T14:11:44.782000+00:00",
    "keyId": "xxxxx-xxxx-x-xxx--xx-xxxxx",
    "startDate": "2019-08-16T14:11:53.862000+00:00",
    "value": null
  }
]
```

Is there an alternative way to get the client secret?

Maybe via the rest api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the service principal secret, you can just get it to see in the creation time. You will never see it anyway after the creation time. So if you forget the service principal secret, you just can reset the secret and then you can get a new one. You can see the messages [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#password-based-authentication):

> Make sure you copy this value - it can't be retrieved. If you forget
>   the password, reset the service principal credentials.

The reset command here:

```
az ad sp credential reset --name yourApplicationName
```

For more details about the command, see [`az ad sp credential reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-credential-reset).

Comment: Hmm, but `az ad sp credential list` will show you the secret, right? So there must be a way to get at it....

Comment: @HongOoi No, you cannot get it anymore after you created it.

Comment: @HongOoi I just verified that with the following code and there is no password: `az ad app create --display-name ServicePrincipalDemo1 --homepage "http://localhost/ServicePrincipalDemo1"  
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalDemo1
az ad sp credential list --id 7e4ac22c-3b86-48fb-9805-0ffc07c2c0dd`

Answer (score 0):

You can't see it after creation, however you can save it to Azure Key Vault and pull the value from there each time you need to make a request.

Comment: This sounds like it has potential. Can you add some code on how to do it? The commands above are workarounds for missing terraform features so if you can give an example with terraform that would be better.