# how to get looged in user from system when AD is on azure cloud

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a desktop application in which we need to login with user logged in email id.

Although for local network drive we getting email id with LDAP protocol like (i.e. in c# with code line - System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress)

But in the case of Azure, we could not able to fetch the email id. I have registered my application in Azure Active directory and able to push my email id user with /users/{email_id}.

But could not able to get logged in email id from system. so that we can push it to Azure with graph API and fetch User object.

Please suggest, how can we get loggedin user's email id in case of Azure Cloud.

Thanks,

A Team

(i.e. in c# with code line - System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress)

(i.e. in c# with code line - System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the logged in users profile for Azure AD OAuth logins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449654/how-do-i-get-the-logged-in-users-profile-for-azure-ad-oauth-logins)

Comment: not really. As we need the logged in user's email address of current machine where user is logged in.

Comment: You still need to do AAD authentication with one of the protocols it supports. If their machine is domain-joined/AAD-joined and SSO is configured correctly, the login screen might not even show for them.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token#integrated-windows-authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As we need the logged in user's email address of current machine where
>   user is logged in.

You can simply call Microsoft Graph API endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` to get the current logged in user's information. See [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: thanks Allen. got it. although i have 1 more doubt .. could we get client id, secret key dynamically ?? is there any API for the same ??

Comment: We can list applications by following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. But there is no way to get the client secret. When you create a new secret on Azure Portal, it's the only time it is available. In fact, you can use powershell to reset the password if necessary, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599160/how-do-i-query-azure-active-directory-for-an-application-client-secret.

Comment: Hi Allen, got your point.  wanted to know we are use /me API to get the user.. although we are getting exception Resource not found with some random ID.. can you suggest what we are missing here ??

Comment: In theory this won't happen because you are already logged in to a user. You can use Fiddler4 to capture the call to see what the request and response are. Please provide relevant screenshots or your code if it is convenient. Be careful not to share any sensitive information. You can also test /me endpoint in Microsoft Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.

Comment: @Allan Kindly refer the below mentioned answer to get screenshot as well as API details

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot for Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVRl3.png)

@Allen - Please check the screenshot below in which code snippet and Exception which we are getting while calling API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/

Comment: Hi allen, awaiting your response. it would be great if you suggest us something as we are getting exception when using the graph API with /me

Comment: Based on your code, you are using client credential authentication, which means there is no "logged in user". In this case, ```/me``` is not supported. You can refer to the permissions for Microsoft Graph Get User: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions. So if you want to get a user, you need to use ```/users/{id | userPrincipalName}```. But based on your another new post, I understand that you don't know the id or userPrincipalName. I think the logic of your needs is incorrect.

Comment: No that you are using client credential authentication, it's unnecessary to get a user and then validate it. We can think of this app as a logged-in user.

Comment: so is there way to get logged in user email address ?

Comment: Do you have a logged in user? As I mentioned above, you don't know the user id, so you cannot log in. And if you don't have a logged in user, how could you get its email address? It doesn't exist.

Comment: we used to get the email address of the user from this code snippet **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress** although for user's whose active directory is on azure. we could not able to fetch the email address from above code snippet.. is it due to some access policy or is there any other way to get the user's email address?